# Is there a way to write a beforeEach globally?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, jestjs

I am trying to write tests with sequelize and I would like to truncate all my tables before each test. I don't want to write that or run that in each test file if possible. Does anyone know of a way to do that?

It seems like jest should support something like that.

I am currently trying to use globalSetup, but that is a beforeAll.

I have another problem which is that when I run globalSetup, I do something like this:

```
  module.exports = () => {                                                                                                                                                                                
    sequelize.db.sync({ force: true })
  }
```

Which works one time out of two. So I'm guessing this is running asynchronously when I need it to run synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

One way :

```
sequelize.db.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    // write you test code here
    // Or
    // or call the function from here to perform your test
})
```

Or you can also do it in this way :

```
// trunk.js

module.exports = () => {                                                                                                                                                                                
    sequelize.db.sync({ force: true })
}

// test.js

const trunk = require('./trunk');

module.exports = () => { 
    trunk.then(() => {
        // write you test code here
    })
}
```

Comment: Hrm... so this simplifies the db cleaning code, but is there a way to put this in a global before each?  Iḿ not a fan of having to repeat a call to clear the db for each test. :(